# Simple Membership and .net Framework 4.0 asp webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.0, simplemembership

I search alot but i did not find any useful answer.

can i use Simple Membership with .net Framework 4.0 in asp webforms ?

because when im trying to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData through Nuget it tells me:

> install-package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data 3.1.2'. You are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but
>   the 
>       package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact
>   the package author.

If i can use it please someone tell me how i should add this on my exist project.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the nuget command line, execute the following:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data -Version 2.0.20710
```

The 2.0.20710 package contains the .NET 4.0 referenced WebMatrix.Data.dll.